# How to implement time ago like facebook

Tags: php, codeigniter

Can anyone explain me the concept of implementing time ago like facebook
in php. I dont want code. I want to know the flow like database field type, whether to use UTC time stamp and to convert to local time.
Thanks

Comment: You can use [timeago](http://timeago.yarp.com/) js plugin and also check [this tut](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vmJBJjzhhVQ).

Answer (score 1):

It is all about your users location. If you have users only at a `single timezone`, then no need of conversion. But if your users are at `different time zones`, then you require a conversion.

In the second scenario, covert and save time in DB as `UTC`, then according to each user location, convert time during fetch.